# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')

Tags: json, typescript, mongodb, routes, next.js

## TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')

Hi I'm using TypeScript with node/Next.js 13 with the new app router and mongoose to push data into a Mongo database but it keeps sending me this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')". The payload shows in the browsers Network section but does not get passed to the database. I'm new to Next.js and TypeScript so I'm sorry if it's something obvious that I've missed but I'm very desperate, I have tried many solutions and none helped. Thaks in advance!

**I'm trying to pass data to a database when a new product is created.**

## product/new/page.tsx

```
"use client"

import Plan from "@/app/components/Plan";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function NewProduct() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    async function createProduct(ev:any) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        await axios.post('../../api/products', {title, description, price});
    }

    return (
        <Plan>
            <div className="max-w-md mx-auto mt-14">
                <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Pievienot jaunu preci</h2>
                <form onSubmit={ createProduct }>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="productName" className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                            Preces nosaukums:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            placeholder="Ievadiet preces nosaukumu"
                            value={title}
                            onChange={ev => setTitle(ev.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="description" className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                            Apraksts:
                        </label>
                        <textarea
                            className="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            placeholder="Ievadiet preces aprakstu"
                            value={description}
                            onChange={ev => setDescription(ev.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="price" className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                            Cena:
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            placeholder="Ievadiet preces cenu"
                            value={price}
                            onChange={ev => setPrice(ev.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-end">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                            Pievienot
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Plan>
    )
}
```

## src/app/api/products/page.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { mongooseConnect } from "../../../../lib/mongoose";
import { Product } from "../../../../models/Product";

export default async function handle(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
        const { method } = req;
        await mongooseConnect();
            console.log({res})
            console.log({req})
            const { title, description, price } = req.body || {};
            const productDoc = await Product.create({
                title,
                description,
                price,
            });
            const data = res.json(productDoc);
            return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

**Console returns this when i tried to debug the res.json:**
`{ res: undefined } { req: { params: {}, searchParams: {} } }`

## models/Product.ts

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
});

export const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

## lib/mongoose.ts

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export function mongooseConnect() {
    const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 1) {
        return Promise.resolve(mongoose.connection);
    } else {
        return mongoose.connect(uri!);
    }
}
```

## lib/mongodb.ts

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "models/Product.js", "src/app/api/products/page.js", "src/app/api/products.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your api `handle` function is failing.

```
export default async function handle(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  // always run async code inside try/catch
  try {
    const { method } = req;
    await mongooseConnect();
    console.log({ res });
    console.log({ req });
    const { title, description, price } = req.body || {};
    // since in schema, title, description, price are required, make sure you sent all
    if (!title || !description || !price){
      console.error("if you are here means you did not pass those correctly")
      // handle accordingly
    }
    const productDoc = await Product.create({
      title,
      description,
      price,
    });
    const data = res.json(productDoc);
    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error in handler", error);
  }
}
```